# Where can I view Contact opportunity role object?

Tags: opportunity, opportunitycontactrole

Can any one tell me where can I view the list of  **Opportunity Contact Role** object  in a separate tab just as  we see  separate tabs for contacts, Leads, Opportunities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

opportunityContactRole is a junction object between Opportunity and Contact.  It can only be customized through the picklist for Role

You view the OCR through either a related list on the Opportunity page layout and/or the Contact page layout.  If not appearing, then customize the page layout to add it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a tab object, it's seen by salesforce as more of a subservient, opportunity-specific object, so no separate tab was deemed necessary.  What purpose are you trying to fill?  Could a report solve your issue?

Comment: I would like to see the list of opportunity contact roles.

Comment: could a report solve your issue?  opps with contact roles?

Answer (score 1):

Contact Roles on the Opportunity can be edited by going to Customize / Opportunities / Contact Roles on Opportunities.

You can't display contact roles on a tab unless you're using a custom object.

Here's a blog post that gives more information on contact roles and examples of the type of picklist values used by other companies.

http://garysmithpartnership.com/contact-roles/

Answer (score 1):

You can view it by:

https://`BaseDomain`.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/OpportunityContactRole/list?filterName=Recent